# How to disable default site?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I used Drupal multisite approach. When I go to `mydomain.com` the default site is loaded and if I deleted `sites/default/settings.php` file, it is creating again.

How do I disable the default site so that, not even the installation page is shown?

Comment: Set redirect rule for main website

Comment: @VishalPatil What do you mean, redirect to what? I don't want to have a default site at all.

Comment: You can redirect to some other website which is active in the same multisite setup instead of disabling the default.

Comment: @VishalPatil Do I have to have a default? Can't it just 404 or something if the requested domain/site doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directory under the `sites` directory besides `default` with the exact name as your domain and place the settings.php file in it. You can delete the default/settings.php after this.

Comment: Don't I need to keep the default.settings.php?

Comment: @macurie The file is just a reference and is not executed. It is copied automatically to settings.php if the server has write permissions to the default directory and when there is no site specific directory. No harm in keeping it as is.

Comment: If I delete `sites/default/settings.php` and go to `http://myip` I get redirected to `http://myip/install.php?profile=myprofile&locale=en`. How do I avoid this?

Comment: @macurie As mentioned in the answer, you have to create the a directory with the same name as the domain inside the sites directory. Create a directory with the domain name (say `mydomain.com`) and place the `settings.php` in it (`sites/mydomain.com/settings.php1`).

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants since it's a multisite and any random domain could potentially trigger the install.php script. He or rather you @macurie need to perform a minimal install with sqlite which will generate a settings.php so the install.php won't appear any more. You have to show something. Either configure the webserver to only allow specific domains or install a default site

Comment: @dalu Ok, would it be reasonable to remove `sites/default` and make it a symlink to another folder in `sites`?

Comment: If there's a site that should be the default site then imho it should be named default. Otherwise it should be named domainname.tld. symlinking is just asking for trouble. You'll have 2 namespaces with the same configuration and errors are bound to happen. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @dalu Do you mean that symlinking dirs in sites is asking in trouble in general, or just in regard to `sites/default`?

Answer (score 0):

You can follw these documents for better understanding of multisite approach in Drupal.
[link1](https://www.drupal.org/node/547860) 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows)

If possible you can mention in your question, which steps you have followed also.

Comment: This doesn't seem helpful. Why do I need to create Apache virtualhosts for each site?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete everything in default/settings.php and write whatever logic you like in settings.php (print message, redirect, just exit, etc ....) and don't forget exit() the the script after you finish.

Also you can choose one of the sites you have to act as a default site just replace the default directory with it.

@see [conf_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/conf_path/7.x) for the code implementation of Drupal multi-site.